# MeasureOverride of custom shape

Tags: wpf

I like to create a custom `Shape` in WPF. It is supposed to look like a "T", a horizontal line on top as wide as possible, a vertical line in the center of the horizontal line.
Since I need the possibility to hide the left side or right side of the horizontal line, I can't set the `Shape` to `Stretch`. But for the sake of simplicity I'm skipping this possibility in my example code.

So, I create a class that inherits from `Shape` and overriding its `DefiningGeometry` property:

```
Public Class MyShape
    Inherits Shape

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property DefiningGeometry As Geometry
        Get
            Return Geometry.Parse(String.Format("M 0,0 L {0},0 M {1},0 L{1},{2}", MyBase.ActualWidth.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                                                                  (MyBase.ActualWidth / 2).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                                                                  MyBase.ActualHeight.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

If I put this custom `Shape` in a `Grid` like this:

```
<Grid>
    <local:MyShape Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
</Grid>
```

it only seems to work like expected. If I make my `Window` wider, my vertical line moves to the right, staying in the center of the horizontal line (like expected). But if I make my `Window` smaller again, the vertical line stays in place, it's not moving to the left, and so it's not staying in the center of my horizontal line.

A little bit of googling brought me to the solution of this problem, I just have to override the `MeasureOverride` function and return the `constraint` parameter.

```
    Protected Overrides Function MeasureOverride(constraint As Size) As Size
        Return constraint
    End Function
```

Now the vertical line stays in the center of the horizontal line, no matter how I resize my `Window`.

---

As long as I use this custom `Shape` stand-alone (like in my test window), everything works fine.

But now I wanted to use this custom `Shape` in a `Template` of another `Control` and when starting my program I get the following `InvalidOperationException`:

`Layout measurement override of element 'MyShape' should not return PositiveInfinity as its DesiredSize, even if Infinity is passed in as available size.`

When I'm debugging, I see that in the `constraint` parameter of the `MeasureOverride` function `Width` and `Height` are both `Infinity`, so returning the `constraint` parameter causes this error to appear.

Since I want my `Shape` to be as wide and high as possible, I don't know what measures to return instad of the `Infinity` constraint.

You can experience this problem when you expand the `Grid` with a `Row` with `Auto` height.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <local:MyShape Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
</Grid>
```

I assume the problem is, that there's no one to decide how high my `Shape` is going to be. The `Row` height is set to `Auto`, and the `Shape` wants to be as high as possible. But shouldn't 'as high as possible' be the height of the container control, in my case the `Window`?

Is there a way to get around this problem in a way that this control works 'on its own', without relying on the parent control to provide the right settings?

Comment: "The Row height is set to Auto, and the Shape wants to be as high as possible" - have you tried to confirm it with any other shape? usually when there no height constraint, elements request minimum height required to show their content

Comment: I tried returning `Double.MaxValue` instead of `Infinity` but that didn't work either.